# Tax Configuration Issue

Tags: tax

Im having a huge issue with setting up tax configuration.

My customer is running eCommerce store in Netherlands. I need to configure 6% VAT for all products irregardless of the shipping address.

I've configured all tax classes for taxable goods, under my tax settings in admin I have product prices set to include tax...

Can someone give me a quick tutorial how to configure this CONSTANT TAX for all the products?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-tax-config-eu) will help you. "Recommended Tax Configuration for EU Stores (Magento CE 1.8 and EE 1.13)"

Comment: It did, but the problem was that the shipping country origin had double database entry in core_config_data table and each time data was saved... the other record was always updated.